# Rails friendly_id pages still attainable by record id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

I'am using the friendly_id gem in my rails app, to create nice clean url's. It's working out good, but the page are also attainable by te record id.

Example:

I've a record with 'name' as slug. This record has 1 for ID.

So the page is attainable from 2 url's:

domain.com/name

and

domain.com/1

I want only to use domain.com/name, so I dont want the page to be attainable from domain.com/1.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the author himself *(Google is your friend; this is a top result when searching `friendly_id disable find id`)*: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/146

> What version of FriendlyId?
>
> With 4.x, just use find_by_slug rather than find.
>
> With 3.x you can use find_by_cached_slug, or check the friendly_id_status of the found result and raise an error if the record was found using something other than the friendly id.

Either way, you need to replace occurences of `find` with one of the alternatives above to tell your application to ignore the `:id` column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really need to learn how to google :S. I've searched for more than an hour.