# Rails: routes whith Friendly id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, friendly-url, friendly-id

First sorry for my english i am french

I am using Frindly_id gem to generate clean url and it work just fine i still have a problem, for example let's say i have a user with user_id=1 and a full_name = = "olivier logaro" so when i go to this user profile i have this url localhost:3000/profile/olivier-logaro so that what i want but the problem is when i go to localhost:3000/profile/1 it will give me the profile of olivier logaro. So what i want is to have acces to the users profile whith just the first url and if i try the second url i will have a error this url doesn't exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is each time you query on a rails 3 app use:

`Profile.find_by_slug(params[:id])`

if you use a rails 4 app

`Profile.find_by slug: params[:id]`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/146.
And its a duplicate ;)
[Rails friendly_id pages still attainable by record id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331305/rails-friendly-id-pages-still-attainable-by-record-id)